# How to copy JARs to the project's folder when adding them in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm working in Eclipse, and I need to add an external JAR to my project, and also copy it to the project's folder so as not to depend on its address on my local machine. Normally I would have copied the JAR manually to the project's lib folder. Problem is, the JAR comes with a lot (and I mean, A LOT) of dependencies on other JARs. I could go hunting for all those dependencies and copy them to my lib folder, but I was wondering if there was a way to avoid having to do that manually.

Comment: This is one of the advantages of using Maven. It would download for you all the dependency jars you need.

Comment: To add, Your project -> Right Click -> properties -> Choose Java Build Path on left pane -> Now choose Libraries tab -> Add External JARs. I am not sure how to copy them to your project automatically.

Comment: Agree with (and upvoted) @janos. "mvn eclipse:eclipse" and "mvn eclipse:clean" make it significantly easier.